# How to do nested pagination on mongoDB aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 3 main collections

```
Blogs{
  id,
  title
}

Comments{
  id,
  message,
  blog_id 
}

Likes{
  id,
  user_id,
  blog_id 
}
```

I want to fetch blogs, their comments, and likes altogether. **Comments should come in pagination 5 at a time** and blog posts are also paginated so also keep in mind that User might just want more comments to show and not Blog posts. **So how to paginate comments without affecting blog's array?**

**Expected output:**

```
{
   _id: "POST_ID"
   title: "STRING",
   comments: [
    {
        commentMessage: "",
        userName: ""
    },
    {
        commentMessage: "",
        userName: ""
    } 
   ]
}
```

**Sample Document:**

```
{
    "_id": "5f987b80811aa021ecce5566",
    "title": "nodejs2",
    "comments": [
        {
            "commentMessage": "this is comment message 2",
            "userName": "user2",
            "createdTime": 123456789
        },
        {
            "commentMessage": "this is comment message 3",
            "userName": "user2",
            "createdTime": 124456789
        },
        {
            "commentMessage": "this is comment message 6",
            "userName": "user2",
            "createdTime": 123456789
        }
    ]
},
```

I have got the expected output but unable to figure out where would I put **$skip** and **$limit** for comment's array.

Here is my sample code, the question is where should I put $skip and $limit to paginate comments

```
BlogPost.aggregate([
            { $match: { $or: [{ title: req.body.title }, { tags: req.body.tag }] } },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: PostComment.collection.name,
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "postId",
                    as: "comments"
                },
            },
             {
                $lookup: {
                    from: PostLike.collection.name,
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "postId",
                    as: "blog_like"
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: User.collection.name,
                    localField: "comments.userId",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "UserDetail",
                },
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$UserDetail"
            },
            {
                $project: 
                      // working code, not an issue
            },
            { $skip: 5},  // for blogs   <=========== if this is wrong, let me know
            { $limit: 5}  // for blogs <=========== if this is wrong, let me know
]).exec((err, blogs) => {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log("blogs: ", blogs)
                return res.send(blogs)
            })
```

Comment: Can you show some sample doc? Probably in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net)?

Comment: Hi @Gibbs, I am not sure what you mean by doc. Do you want to see the actual output? Sorry, I am new to MongoDB.

Comment: While projecting you can $slice comments

Comment: Hi @BiswaBhusan but how does it work when user want to see more comments? if he clicks on more and query runs again, won't that give new blogs as well in output?

Comment: I think you can make your query design more flexible by fetching blogs and each blog id passed to another query which is again paginated

Comment: I meant sample documents.

Comment: @Gibbs I have attached sample doc.

Comment: @BiswaBhusan I tried with $slice and it works but only if I have no other operation on the same variable. Actually, I am using $map on comments array in project already.

Comment: You have to extend the pipeline with one more project

Comment: that works. one issue solved. thanks, mate :) now I just need to figure out how to separate two paginations so that one does not affect other